# Oracle listener create logon

Tags: oracle

I would like to prepare listner in another port but I have got problems you can see this in picture with I added below. Also I would like to connect to dabase using this "listener" and check connection in CMD using easy connect.

My username: rafal password:oracle 
listener in 1521 is working but in another port I have got problem

[image]

Comment: can you post your listener.ora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No listener" error indicates either that you're reaching the wrong server, or the right server on the wrong port, or that the listener is not started. I would start by checking that the listener is started, since you can reach the other one.

Comment: server is ok but I`m not sure about port I wrote there 1522 but I think I have to create this port before I will give this port into listener? If I think correct my question is: where can I create new port for new listener.

Comment: What you might have to do is modify the firewall to allow traffic on that port, but I'm not sure that a firewall issue would appear to have the same ORA-12541 symptom. Perhaps others can comment.